# Notepad++ Load langs.xml failed (Windows 7 home premium)

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I tried to make notepad++ the default program I used this `.bat`:

```
rem START BATCH COMMANDS
rem PLEASE MAKE SURE THAT USER ACCOUNT CONTROL (UAC) IS TURNED OFF AND PC HAS BEEN REBOOTED FIRST!
rem If you are using Vista x32 version, then edit this file first by adding “rem ” in front of every line that contains the phrase “syswow64?. Then run the script again.
@echo off
PAUSE

takeown /f C:\Windows\syswow64\notepad.exe
cacls C:\Windows\syswow64\notepad.exe /G Administrators:F

takeown /f C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
cacls C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe /G Administrators:F

takeown /f C:\Windows\notepad.exe
cacls C:\Windows\notepad.exe /G Administrators:F

copy C:\Windows\syswow64\notepad.exe C:\Windows\syswow64\notepad.exe.backup
copy C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe.backup
copy C:\Windows\notepad.exe C:\Windows\notepad.exe.backup

copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe C:\Windows\syswow64\notepad.exe
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe C:\Windows\notepad.exe
@echo on
rem END BATCH COMMANDS
```

This seemed to work it copied the files fine but now if I try to edit a .txt this happens:

[image]

If I click on the notepad++ or the modified notepad.exe it opens fine. How can I get this working?

Comment: +1. I'm on xp and the answer from @st worked. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, that may have worked but I found I program that installs and makes notepad++ the default 
all in one shot. It worked great. And I haven't have the langs trouble since, unfortunately
I do not remember where I downloaded it from but I do have a drop IO link I just made...

http://tinyurl.com/28fsdl6

Hope its not against the rules to post DL links if so I apologize in advance.

Comment: Just so everyone knows...I couldn't remember my log in info so I singed in as my alias Josh Goodman. LOL

Answer (score 3):

from http://www.seangw.com/wordpress/index.php/2010/05/notepad-load-langs-xml-failed-and-how-to-fix-it/

1.Open your “Notepad++” installation folder (right click on the shortcut icon, “Open File Location”)

2.Rename / Delete “langs.xml” to a backup (langs.xml.bak or something to that affect)

3.Copy “langs.model.xml”

4.Rename the new “langs.model.xml” to “langs.xml”

5.Restart Notepad++

Comment: +1. Thanks very much for this. I'm on xp, but I followed your directions and it worked. One small detail, Step 4 should be, "Paste the copied file". Then so on. Regards,

Comment: I did that but still same thing notepad++ will open from both of the exe files (notepad++.exe and the notepad++.exe that is now called notepad.exe in c:\windows)   and shortcuts I can even drop a .txt or .bat file onto the desktop shortcut to notepad++ and it works fine but if I right click on a *.txt it gives the error.... (win7)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Notepad++ with Administrator privileges? Check by right-clicking the `notepad++.exe` -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Make sure the "Run as Administrator" box is unticked and the program is not run in compatibility mode.

And where did you get the batch script from?

Comment: I really don't remember where I got the script for. I apologize, next time I post something I didn't wright I will be sure to include such information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue form months. I wanted to use notepad++ but... langs.xml kept becoming corrupted every now and then. The solution that worked at the end was to do to the application folder and make the file read-only.